# Revoking certificate in c# with ICertAdmin2::RevokeCertificate method

Tags: c#, certificate-authority

How to import certadm.dll into managed project and use RevokeCertificate method? I tried adding it as reference but I got error asying it's not assembly or COM object.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I already tried *regsvr32 c:\certadm.dll* and I get following error:
***LoadLibrary("c:\certadm.dll") failed - the specified procedure could not be found.***

Comment: You might want to have a look at the version of certadm.dll that you're trying to register.  You can use DLL Export Viewer (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) to check that the requisite COM load/unload procedures are there.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old question, but i cannot find any example of using ICertAdmin2::RevokeCertificate  in c#. I think it is usefull to write exaple here.

1 Add certadmin lib

[image]

2 Use this code

```
public static void RevokeCert(string connection,string serial)
{
    //connection= "192.168.71.128\\My-CA"
    //serial = "614870cd000000000014"

    const int CRL_REASON_UNSPECIFIED = 0;

    CERTADMINLib.CCertAdmin _admin = null;
    try
    {
        _admin = new CCertAdmin();
        _admin.RevokeCertificate(connection, serial, CRL_REASON_UNSPECIFIED, DateTime.Now);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (_admin != null)
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_admin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding to this answer, to creat the certadminLib I had to run "tlbimp certadm.dll" to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to register the COM server using `regsvr32` before it will be available to be added as a reference in Visual Studio.

e.g.,

```
regsvr32 certadm.dll
```