# Code to revoke a Microsoft CA certificate from outside the domain

Tags: c#, .net, certificate-authority

I am trying to develop a .NET application to revoke a certificate obtained from a Microsoft CA.

I was able to get it working using `ICertAdmin::RevokeCertificate` and the pointers given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227367/revoking-certificate-in-c-sharp-with-icertadmin2revokecertificate-method).

However, I find that the revocation works only if I run this application from a computer that is connected to the same domain as the CA. When run from a non-domain joined computer, it fails with the following error message:

> CCertAdmin::RevokeCertificate: The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba (WIN32: 1722 RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE)

Now, my question is:

1. Is this how `ICertAdmin` is supposed to work?
2. If yes, is there any way to programmatically revoke certificates from outside a domain?

Comment: IMHO makes sense forcing only trusted users (users withing the domain) to modify the certificates. You could always develop a webservice with anonymous authentication and runs under a domain account that contains the revocation logic. Anyway, consider that webservice dangerous (you dont want everybody tampering your certificates)

Comment: @bradbury9 - Thank you for the comment. I guess allowing only domain accounts to revoke certificates does make sense.